# I want to add Time?

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, document.evaluate

I have a auto submit or `Click` (button) code, i want to add time delay for 2 seconds in this code?

**Code Here :**

```
document.evaluate("//input[@value='Submit Now' and @type='submit' and contains(@class, 'button')]", document, null, 9, 
null).singleNodeValue.click();
```

Please Help,
Thank you!

Comment: Thread.sleep(2000); didnt work?

Comment: Is this about Java or Javascript?

Comment: He has 1 points i guess he tried to write java-script.

Comment: @Umer: Java != Javascript!!!!!

Comment: java is absolutely different with javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a javascript issue, you tagged is as 'java' and 'script'.

To delay this in javascript, you can pass it into the setTimeout function like so:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.evaluate("//input[@value='Submit Now' and @type='submit' and contains(@class, 'button')]", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue.click();
}, 2000);
```

That should do it.